# iText Xtra 5.5.9 dependency is missing

Tags: itext

Is there a problem with the POM file for iText Xtra?

org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-SNAPSHOT cannot be found:

Here is the info from the POM file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url> 
          https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
      </url>
      <releases>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: This is from the Apache Commons website: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/ looks the same to me?

Comment: Have you tried it? If you actually put that dependency in your POM file you will see that it does not get resolved.

Comment: Sorry, it'll have to wait until Monday. Public holidays here in Belgium, the office is closed.

Comment: That's fine. I can wait. Let me know what you find. Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: Do you have an update regarding this issue?

Comment: I forgot all about it. Sorry. But there is another issue. iText 5 is targeted at Java 5, and the Apache project has decided to switch `commons-imaging` to Java 7. That appeared on our radar only yesterday. The dependency is only used in the pdfcleanup package, so if you don't use that, there is a workaround: 1. Get the iText source from GitHub 2. Remove pdfcleanup from xtra 3. Remove the dependency from the pom file 4. Compile xtra from source 5. Manually add the jar to your project.

Comment: Thanks, but pdfcleanup is exactly what I was using. I would like to use pdfSweep in iText 7 but I don't see any examples. Do you have an example like [this one](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/content-extraction-and-redaction/removing-content) showing how to remove content with pdfSweep in iText 7? Thanks.

Comment: Is PDFCleanup broken, then?

Comment: I have contacted Apache Commons.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I hope this gets resolved.

Comment: Looks like commons-imaging has been deprecated as it no longer appears on the Apache Nexus Repository server. All our builds are failing!!